# Dynamics CRM 2011 for Outlook, Regarding pane not showing on email

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Have installed the Outlook for CRM 2011 add-in along with Rollup 12 on a Win 7 machine running Outlook 2013. When the user opens an email and click "Set Regarding", she can select an contact, but the email form does not change to show the "regarding pane" at the bottom. The "Track" button does change to "Untrack", so it seems that it is working, just not showing.

I've uninstalled/reinstalled more than once to no avail. It does work on other machines in my office.

Comment: What is the version of your Office? A customer reporter a similar issue today.

Comment: This has happened for the same person on both Outlook 2010 and now Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the person's personal settings for the CRM in Outlook. If you go under the Email tab there is a check box for "check incoming e-mail in Outlook and determine whether an email should be linked and saved as a CRM record. If that box is checked it may be causing the issue you are describing above.

I have had the exact same issue and making sure that box is unchecked solves it everytime. I've asked in multiple dynamics crm forums, even our Microsoft partner, and no one has been able to explain why, but having that box checked definitely made the regarding fields on outlook emails disappear and not show up.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however, the box was not checked.